# I changed Functions.php and now I get "cannot decode raw data NSURLErrorDomain:-1015" (not blank)

Tags: functions

I'm desperated...

I added some code to the file functions.php (from wp-includes in Filezilla), and now I get "cannot decode raw data NSURLErrorDomain:-1015" in Safari;

"Es posible que la página web en http://carolinacomposto.com/ no funcione temporalmente o se haya trasladado de manera permanente a una nueva dirección web." in Chrome.

As I read many of you with this problem see a white page, I don't see anything, just that message.

I DO CAN access to wp-admin panel.

I don't have backup :(

I tried to delete the last code I added, but still doesn't work.

This is the code I added:

[image: This is the code]

I'm so scared and don't know what to do, I did A LOT of changes in my design... please HELP!

Answer (score 1):

So first you should **not** modify any of the core WordPress files, ever. Otherwise, your changes will be lost the next time you upgrade WP.

Instead you want to modify your *theme's* function file (if it is your own theme) or make a child theme and modify *its* functions.php file. (if you are using someone else's theme)

As for figuring out the error, it will usually appear in your web server's logs. If you can access those, and show us the error, we should be able to help out.

Assuming you only changed that one file, another option would be to download a fresh copy of WordPress on your computer, grab the wp-includes/functiosn.php file from that fresh copy and replace the one you modified with it. At least then you'll know for sure you are back to the original file.

But don't panic, don't do anything else in code until you've figured this out, just to be sure we don't lose anything. Everything you've done is probably still there - just not loading correctly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, thank you for your answer!  That was what I was trying to do... to change my theme functions.php file. I already tried to download it again un replace it with the new functions.php but still doesn't work... Also tried to update Wordpress from dashboard. 

My web server's log is empty! Or I'm looking at the wrong place... so I can't show you. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. Are you sure you didn't change anything, maybe with your server's or PHP settings? Or maybe your hosting provider changed something?